# django, who to excess data from models and user it as a conditional in templates

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have profileinfo model that is linked to user model. there are two usertypes student and teacher. I want to display "add courses" link  if user is authenticated and usertype is Teacher. if not link should not appear on navbar

I have tried following code in templates

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index'%}">YFEA Academy</a>
          </div class= "nav navbar-nav-right">
          {% if user.is_authenticated and user.ProfileInfo.UserType == 'Teacher' %}
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Add Courses</a></li>
          </ul>
          {%endif%}
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="{% url 'app:logout'%}">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>

          {% else%}
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="{% url 'app:register'%}">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'app:login'%}">login</a></li>
          </ul>
          {%endif%}
        </div>
      </nav>

    {%block body%}

    {% endblock %}
  </div>
  </body>
</html>

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User ,related_name = 'ProfileInfo')
    choices= (('S','Student'),('T','Teacher'))
    UserType = models.CharField(max_length = 50 , choices = choices)
    picture = models.FileField(upload_to = 'media', default = None)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not have mixed naming conventions - convert all the attrs to lower case. Same for relation names.
2. `user = models.ForeignKey`, I suppose, is meant to be a `OneToOne` field actually
3. `user_type` which accepts values from "choices" only, actually [stores](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#choices) the *value*, not the title/descr/display name. Which are: `'S'` and `'T'`. So comparison to 'Teacher' will never give `True`.

Comment: what is the difference between foerignKey and OneToOneField

Comment: FK usually means 1:M, OneToOne is 1:1. Current model allows multiple UserProfile's per single User